# Synopsys Detect with zip file

Tags: blackduck, synopsis-detect

I am new to [Blackduck](https://www.synopsys.com/software-integrity/security-testing/software-composition-analysis.html) and exploring it.

In the `Synopsys Detect`, I am trying to scan a file system including `zip` files.
I have the project created in the **Black Duck server**.
I have added the server configuration also with the API token having read and write access.

Somehow I am still getting an error.

```
EXCEPTIONS:
Create or Locate Project
Request failed authorization [HTTP Error]: There was a problem trying to POST https://blackduck.wolterskluwer.com/api/projects, response was 403 Forbidden.
```

I tried providing **Application ID** also but could not make any headway.

Any pointer will be of great help.

Comment: did you find a resolution?

Comment: Yes. They have updated the authentication. So, have to use the code generated with selected access rights from Blackduck UI.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "use the code generated with selected access rights"?  Was the authentication updated from Black Duck?

Comment: @Paradox Yes, they changed that. Now you need to provide a token for it.